# Changing the home screen location of a mobile app

Tags: android, ios

I know this is a strange question, but I am trying to make an app to curb procrastination.

So basically, I want it to randomly shuffle the location of specific app icons from page 1 to 3, then to 2 and then 5 every 30 minutes. Is this possible? I imagine because of permissions and privacy, my app would not know the location or be able to change the location of other apps.

I looked into this 4 years ago and it was not possible, but tech evolves everyday.

Comment: It is not possible on iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android you could write your own launcher.  But that would be the only way to do it.

Comment: Thanks! I’m gonna try it out. After researching it a bit from your answer, I think it will work.